# How is "recent" defined when using recentmenu extension?

Tags: extension, menu

the recentmenu extension is a nice feature.   How does it define recent?   by number - e.g. last 12 items?  Or date?   this week, etc.

Answer (score 2):

You can set preference by going to Administer > System Settings > Misc (Undelete, PDF,.......)

[image]

Comment: That sounds right. Looking at [the code](https://github.com/civicrm/org.civicrm.recentmenu/blob/33c9ca1da007c4e3d3ecc24edb5818e5f55e6dc6/recentmenu.php#L191) it just uses `CRM_Utils_Recent::get()` from core so should obey the core admin setting.